# Azure Function couldnt find document openXML

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions

I am new in Azure Functions and i am try to discover some features of it.

So i created function blob trigger, added references of OpenXML sdk in project.json

```
"frameworks": {
"net46":{
  "dependencies": {
    "WindowsAzure.Storage": "7.0.0" ,
    "Open-XML-SDK" : "2.7.2",
    "DocumentFormat.OpenXml" : "2.8.1"
```

And in run.csx i added next code

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using Microsoft.Azure;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Presentation;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml;

public static  void Run (Stream myBlob, string name, TraceWriter log) 
{
            // *While we upload a blob, function start to execute*
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(myBlob);
            string S = reader.ReadToEnd();
            int numberofSlides = CountSlides(S);
            log.Info($"Number of slides = {numberofSlides}");

}

 // *here, using XML sdk we open our presentation without using Office*

 public static int CountSlides(string presentationFile)
        {
 using (PresentationDocument presentationDocument =PresentationDocument.Open(presentationFile, false))
            {
                return CountSlides(presentationDocument);
            }
        }

        public static int CountSlides(PresentationDocument presentationDocument)
        {
            if (presentationDocument == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("presentationDocument");
            }

            int slidesCount = 0;

            PresentationPart presentationPart = presentationDocument.PresentationPart;
            if (presentationPart != null)
            {
                slidesCount = presentationPart.SlideParts.Count();
            }

            return slidesCount;
        }
```

The problem is while i upload a .pptx , i have error in log

> Exception while executing function: Functions.BlobTriggerCSharp1. mscorlib: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. DocumentFormat.OpenXml: Could not find document.

I upload a file .pptx using Microsoft Azure Storage Explorer and I can not understand why i have an error.

Comment: you might be missing anything that's why you getting an error while uploading file refer to this link for step by step guide and see if it helps. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vs-azure-tools-storage-explorer-blobs#managing-blobs-in-a-blob-container

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the [following method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc562287(v=office.14).aspx):

```
public static PresentationDocument Open(
    string path,
    bool isEditable
)
```

The first parameter it accepts is `path` but you pass the file contents in there. It tries to find this weird file path and throws exception.

Try using the [Stream overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc536282(v=office.14).aspx).